# AngularJS in mobile Safari: <select> with ng-change keeps opening the dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile-safari

In AngularJS, I have a simple  dropdown with ng-change to make it redirect (change state) when the value changes. It works everywhere except in mobile Safari (like on my iPhone). Basically it's a Grade selector, and picking a grade reloads this page and shows content for the selected grade.

It initially works (I click the dropdown, it shows the iOS's native selector UI for my options, I select another Grade, press "Done", and it reloads this page with the new Grade), however if I press any other button (completely unrelated to this ), the  opens up again as if I had pressed the .

```
<select ng-options="Course.CourseId as (Course.CourseTitle) for Course in Courses" ng-change="ChangeCourse(Course.CourseId)" ng-model="Course.CourseId"></select>
```

The function simply does a state change with the new CourseId:

```
$scope.ChangeCourse = function(CourseId) {
    $state.go("Editor.Course", { CourseId: CourseId });
};
```

Any ideas why mobile Safari is having trouble?

Comment: `ng-model="Course.CourseId"` -- can this be a problem? Try changing it to some other variable. Do you see any error in the console?